# Matlab simulated Annealing with two vector decision variables

Tags: matlab, optimization, vector, simulated-annealing

I have an objective function which takes two distinct vector (price1 and price2) decision variables each 24 elements long and evaluate to a scaler value. 
`profit = sum(sum(W.*price1(1:4)) + sum(Y(1:24).*price2(1:24))`
I want to get an optimized values for these two vectors (price1 and price2) using Matlab simulannealbnd function. I am not sure whether this Matlab function can take two vectors as input at a time and optimize or I have to do iteratively, optimize price1 while fixing price2 vice versa.

Comment: write a function (objective function) with two inputs and one output. `o = objfun(price1,price2)` then pass that to the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks NKN, I was able solve it, by combining values in one vector and handling them inside objective function.